# How can I test a server using gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, jetty

I have a server, written in Java, that's my application, and I want to run some tests on it. I'm using gradle to manage dependencies and build tasks and stuff, so I want to use that for this too. I need to start up the server and then run my unit tests which make a bunch of HTTP requests against it and then ideally even shut down the server when the tests are done. So I tried adding to my build.gradle `test.dependsOn(jettyRunWar)`, (jettyRunWar is what runs the server), but I guess that was too simple because `gradle test` never returns from jettyRunWar to proceed with the tests. Can I wire it up such that gradle will start the server and then runs the tests?

Comment: have you considered [using junit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20707017/how-to-run-junit-tests-with-gradle) , [or like this here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/gradle-goodness-running-single)

Comment: Right, I'm trying to use JUnit, but if I try to run my server so I can run my tests then gradle doesn't return from the task that runs the server so it never runs the tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah! Ya gotta add

```
jettyRunWar {
    daemon = true
}
```

to your build.gradle. And then if you wanna shut down the server at the end ya gotta throw in this too:

```
stopPort = 1234
stopKey = 'stopKey'
// gradle is luser. Full story (and code copied from): https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2263
import org.gradle.api.plugins.jetty.internal.Monitor
[jettyRun, jettyRunWar]*.doLast {
    /**
     * THIS IS A WORKAROUND! THE CURRENT VERSION OF THIS TASK DOESN'T START A WATCHER IN DAEMON MODE
     *
     * If starting the monitor fails, it may be because the jetty task was updated to fix this issue
     * When that happens, we shouldn't need the custom task any more
     *
     * Copied From: AbstractJettyRunTask
     */
    if (getStopPort() != null && getStopPort() > 0 && getStopKey() != null) {
        Monitor monitor = new Monitor(getStopPort(), getStopKey(), server.getProxiedObject());
        monitor.start();
    }
}
```

Make sure you include the comment about "gradle is luser".

Comment: Pretty nice, now I only have to find out [how to do this with a Spring Boot server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65629920/how-to-create-typescript-angular-client-from-spring-boot-server-in-gradle-task).