# Gradle Tests inside main sources

Tags: java, gradle, junit, spring-boot

I'm writing web service to run tests over junit using web endpoint, for this reason I have to keep all tests in sources.
The problem is that I want run tests dirctly from IDEA and command line, and with last I've stucked.

How can I run tests inside sources folder (src/main/java) through "gradle test"?
I'm not fammiliar with gradle, but I've tried to use

```
sourceSets {
    test {
        java.srcDir file('src/main/java')
        resources.srcDir file('src/main/resources')
    }
}
```

But it breaks project import using IDEA, my 2016.1.1 sometimes can't create two modules with same content root or expectedly marks sources as tests.

Can I solve this problem with customizing `test {}`, or somehow load test sources into SpringBoot launcher for web service?

Maybe I can extend gradle test task and customize it?

Comment: Can you explain again, why do you need to have test sources in main sourceset `src/main/java` and not in test sourceset `src/test/java`?

Comment: @Nikem All these tests used for integration testing and should be abble to run by self-hosted service. All tests are java-written using JUnit with custom extensions. For example `testservice.application.com/run/class/NewFeatureTest` will run `NewFeatureTest.class` which makes some requests to development/production environment like `production.application.com/api/` and does asserts on retrieved data. And I have to store `NewFeatureTest.java` inside main sources to be visible from service this testing service.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the `file()` calls

```
sourceSets {
    test {
        java.srcDir 'src/main/java'
        resources.srcDir 'src/main/resources'
    }
}
```

Tested on gradle 5.4.1 but should work on other versions too

Answer (score -1):

I guess this post can help you to leanr how to start the tests inside the main sources:

[How to run junit tests with gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20707017/how-to-run-junit-tests-with-gradle).

I would specify one subfiolder in source which shall contain all your tests.
And you can specify the output directory, which should be different to the default output directory:

```
sourceSets {
    test {
        java.srcDir file('src/main/java/tests') // tests shall contain your tests
        resources.srcDir file('src/main/resources')
        output.resourcesDir = "build/classes/main"
    }
}
```

Comment: I saw it, and already have tried this approach. It works, but as I mentioned in question it breaks Intellij IDEA project import from gradle.

Comment: Reworked my answer to hopefully be not useless anymore.